# How let feature branch merged to master but only listed with 1 commit in master?

Tags: git, git-flow

I'd like to following strategy of git feature branch merging:
1.local feature branch have all the detail commit history against that branch;
2.when merged into master branch, i want only 1 commit representing all the feature branch commits.
How to implement that, or is that possible?

Thanks~!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your requirement.  The default behavior for a `git merge` is that there would be only one commit in `master` from a feature branch which is merged in.  Can you clarify your question?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, my question is: if i git merge with --no-ff, or rebase first then git merge, there will be a lot of so small granularity commits. This will polute the history on master branch. I'd like : for master branch , only feature level commit is there, not detail coding commit stay there.

Comment: Can you give us a diagram showing the workflow between the various branches?  This would also make your question more helpful to others in the future.